# Implementing simple slideToggle effect on navigation menu images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slide, slidetoggle

I have successfully implemented a slideToggle effect on a navigation bar item/image.  You can see the effect [here](http://salliannputman.com/test.html).

I was hoping that slideToggle would slide the hidden DIV/image straight down, rather than the effect I am seeing which is more of a curved/flip effect (I hope you are following me!).  Is there a way of getting this effect using just jQuery?

Here is the CSS:

```
li#home {
    background: url('images/home.png') no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
}

img.hover {
    display: none;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li id="home"><a href="index.html" class=""><img src="images/home-hover.png" width="120px" height="40px" class="hover"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the script:

```
$('li#home').hover(function () {
    $('img.hover').slideToggle('medium');
    });
```

Because I couldn't get this working I also tried implementing jQuery UI, with the slide effect included, and this script, but I got no effect at all with this:

```
$('li#home').hover(function () {
      $('img.hover').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

I'd rather not use jQuery UI if possible.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the CSS to this:

```
li#home {
    background: url('http://salliannputman.com/images/home.png') no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

img.hover {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    display: none;
}

.nav {
    background-color:#292929;
    padding:20px;
}
```

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7z9/10/)

Comment: I have done this and it doesn't make any difference to the slide effect.

Comment: @Nick - think it might be because slideToggle is getting fired twice. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the slide effect still looks the same

Comment: @Nick - do you think you could sandbox the problem at jsfiddle.net so it's easier for me/us to mess with?

Comment: sure, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/Lj7z9/).  Everything is probably working as it is supposed to, it's just that the effect doesn't look like I want it to look.  What I was hoping for is that the colour of the text can fill from the top to the bottom on hover.  Do you know if there is a way of achieving this?  Thanks.

Comment: @Nick - edited again, I think it's a slight improvement over the previous state of affairs.

Comment: What I mean by this is that there is a reveal effect, i.e. the hidden div is in place, but is revealed gradually.

Comment: @Nick - then I'm pretty sure you'll need a different approach, such as expanding a white background over an translucent image.

Comment: Thanks. Is there not a jQuery effect for reveal?